# How to pass SQS attributes when IOT rule is triggered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-iot

**Basic flow:** Multiple clients are pushing data to the single AWS IOT topic which then pushes the same data to SQS after authentication and there's a backend service which is listening to SQS.

For authentication, I've created a custom authorizer. Following is the dummy response from the custom authorizer.

```
{
    "isAuthenticated": true,
    "refreshAfterInSeconds": 600,
    "policyDocuments": [
        "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Action\":\"iot:Publish\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:iot:ap-south-1:test:topic/customauthtesting\"}]}"
    ],
    "disconnectAfterInSeconds": 3600,
    "principalId": "123",
    "context" ": {
         "userId" : "User1"    
    }
}
```

And I'm able to pass the body(incl. timestamp) to SQS using IOT Rule query statement like this
`SELECT *, timestamp() as timestamp FROM 'topic/test'`

Now, I want to push the context.userId either as an attribute or in a body to SQS when the same IOT rule is triggered, but I'm unable to do so. It's mentioned in the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/custom-authorizer.html that *Information derived after validating the token that is made available in AWS IoT rules engine SQL statements*, so I think it's feasible to do so.

Can someone please provide me the example or the correct syntax for passing the userId in Rule SQL query if possible.
Let me know if more info is required.

Comment: Have you tried using the `principal()` function to see what it returns? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-principal

Comment: What did `principal()` return? The docs also state that the context is available in a policy variable (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

Comment: principal() returns `principalId`(shown in the above response) provided that it should be of format [a-zA-Z0-9]*, otherwise it results in an error if used in the rules. 
I want to use the context in SQL rule statement. Not sure that policy variable would work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Old but still not answered.
In order to attach the additional information to the body message in nested object `context` the SQL should be like this:

`SELECT *, timestamp() as timestamp, clientid() as context.client_id, principal() as context.principal FROM 'topic/test'`